# What is wrong with this function

Tags: javascript, function

What is wrong with this function and how can I fix it, I have been trying to figure it out but i can't. Even if I call the function with load() it still returns that load is undefined, why?

```
function lоаd(){ аlert('Hello!'); } window.onload = load;
```

Comment: how is it you managed to use `cyrillic o, cyrillic a, cyrillic a, latin o, latin o, latin o, latin a, latin o, latin a` in the one line of code?

Comment: The code was handed down to me and I had to find the error in it, but I didn't notice that it was with different ASCII characters and I was going insane trying to find the error in the logic

Comment: how did someone else other than you manage to use cyrillic o, cyrillic a, cyrillic a, latin o, latin o, latin o, latin a, latin o, latin a in the one line of code?

Comment: It's probably on purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with those characters. Retyping `load` and `alert` fixes the issue for me. So I'm guessing there might be some hidden ASCII characters somewhere in them. (Quentin explains the reason in his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51170307/5894241)

Here's the updated snippet:

```js
function lоаd() {
  аlert('Hello!');
}
window.onload = load;
```

Here's your current snippet for reference:

```js
function lоаd() {
  alert('Hello!');
}
window.onload = lоаd;
```

Answer (score 8):

When you wrote:

> ```
> function lоаd(){ аlert('Hello!'); }
> ```

You used:

```
U+006C : LATIN SMALL LETTER L
U+043E : CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER O
U+0430 : CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A
U+0064 : LATIN SMALL LETTER D
```

When you wrote:

> ```
> window.onload = load;
> ```

You used:

```
U+006C : LATIN SMALL LETTER L
U+006F : LATIN SMALL LETTER O
U+0061 : LATIN SMALL LETTER A
U+0064 : LATIN SMALL LETTER D
```

---

**You have to use the same name**. You can't expect different names using different characters which happen to look similar to mean the same thing.